# sed not replacing string in file

Tags: sed

```
ka@karl:~/dev/say/coverage$ sed -i 's/http/httpLOL/g' index.html 
ka@karl:~/dev/say/coverage$ cat index.html 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here. Was expecting `<!doctype html>` to become `<!doctype htmlLOL>`.

Comment: Just a tip: read your commands closely.

Comment: Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees... Even after 5 times reading ... that is just normal. That's why we have the concept of proofreading.

Comment: Typo: `http` should have been `html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think `html` will be replaced, if you tell `sed` to replace `http`?

Try:

```
sed -i 's/html/htmlLOL/g' index.html
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thanks! Need more coffee...

Comment: or less marihuana or alcohol ;-)

Comment: Alcohol. Just pure alcohol..